# Check if a string is a permutation of a palindrome using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, complexity, palindrome

This is a solution to exercise 1.4 from Cracking the Coding Interview written using Python 3.

Given a string, write a function to check if it is a permutation of a palindrome.

> Example: 'Tact Coa'
>
> Output: True (permutations: "taco cat", "atco cta", etc.)

I wanted to get feedback on making my code clearer and more pythonic.  I believe my code has time complexity \$O(n)\$ and space complexity \$ O(n)\$ is that correct?  If so, is there any way to improve on either the space or time complexity?

```
from collections import Counter


def is_palindrome_permutation(data: str) -> bool:
    """Given a string, check if it is a permutation of a palindrome."""
    data = data.lower().replace(' ', '')
    num_odd = sum(1 for char, freq in Counter(data).items() if char != ' ' and freq % 2 == 1)
# Check for two types of palindromes , 1) Odd Length (e.g. abc cba) 2) Even Length (e.g. abc d cba)
    if num_odd == 1 and len(data) % 2 == 1 or num_odd == 0 and len(data) % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Test

> datum = 'Tac4t co@A @4'
>
> print(is_palindrome_permutation(datum))

Result

> True

Test

> datum = 'Tac4t co@A @4s'
>
> print(is_palindrome_permutation(datum))

Result

> False

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. You strip out spaces, then on the next line check if each character is a space.  The second part is redundant.
2. The only possible values for `freq % 2` are `0` and `1`, so `num_odd = sum(1 for char, freq in Counter(data).items() if char != ' ' and freq % 2 == 1)` can be simplified as `num_odd = sum(freq % 2 for Counter(data).values())`
3. If `num_odd` is `0`, then there must be an even number of elements. If `num_odd` is `1`, then there must be an odd number of elements.  So really all you care about is if there is more than 1 odd count.
4. You can return the results of expressions directly.  So something like `return x < y` is simpler than using an `if` test and manually returning `True` or `False` depending on the outcome.
5. I would put the `replace` first since that reduces the number of characters that `lower` has to operate over (although this is probably a silly negligible micro optimization).

So the code can be simplified to:

```
from collections import Counter


def is_palindrome_permutation(data: str) -> bool:
    """Given a string, check if it is a permutation of a palindrome."""
    data = data.replace(' ', '').lower()
    return sum(freq%2 for freq in Counter(data).values()) < 2
```

One more thing you could do is put the `Counter` on the first line.  I think this hurts readability a bit, but does mean that your modified `data` can be garbage collected right away.  There is no point doing this with `.values()`, though, since this is just a view into the `Counter` object, so the `Counter` object has to be kept in memory.

```
from collections import Counter


def is_palindrome_permutation(data: str) -> bool:
    """Given a string, check if it is a permutation of a palindrome."""
    data = Counter(data.replace(' ', '').lower())
    return sum(freq%2 for freq in data.values()) < 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if num_odd == 1 and len(data) % 2 == 1 or num_odd == 0 and len(data) % 2 == 0:
```

is a long way to say

```
if num_odd == len(data) % 2:
```

---

```
if condition:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

is a long way to say

```
return condition
```

---

You don't need to check that `char != ' '`: you already filtered them out one line above. In any case, stick to a Single Responsibility Principle. If you count odd occurrences, just count them.

Comment: do you recommend changing num_odd to odd_occurences?